# How to add some text in google piechart pieHole

Tags: google-visualization, pie-chart

visualization.PieChart`with`pieHole`, I just want to give some custom text inside`pieHole` is this possible? Any idea how to do his?
My code is

```
                 var chart6 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart6'));
                chart6.draw(data, {width: 650, height: 259, title: 'Browser bounce rate',
                    colors:['#058DC7','#50B432','#ED561B','#EDEF00','#24CBE5','#64E572'],
                    areaOpacity: 0.1,
                    pieHole: 0.4,
                    hAxis: {textPosition: 'in', showTextEvery: 5, slantedText: false, textStyle: { color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 10 } },
                    pointSize: 5,
                    chartArea:{left:0,top:30,width:"100%",height:"100%"}
                });
```

Comment: The only way I could find to do this was to overlay the text using divs. Be interesting to see if anyone knows how to do it using the options.

Answer (score 1):

There are no chart options that will let you put text in the hole; you have to layer other elements on top of your chart.

If you don't have to worry about older versions of IE, you can actually layer the HTML under the chart instead of on top, and set the chart's `backgroundColor` option to "transparent".  This will let the text show through the hole, but won't block any mouse interactions with the chart.  If you have to code for IE < 9 as well, you have to layer on top (at least in IE < 9), as the Visualization API does not support transparency in IE < 9.